# I deleted a post, is there a way to add comments to explain why I deleted it?

Tags: discussion, comments, deleted-posts

I have just deleted a question in Meta Exchange - I reported a bug but worked out the problem was due to a browser plug-in not Meta Exchange. 
Someone commented on the post before I deleted it.

Is there a way to send a message to the commentor to explain why I deleted the post?

Comment: You can comment first, then delete. But usually, no, you will not be able to send a message to someone specific. In this case, the someone is a moderator so they will see deleted questions and the comments on them ;)

Comment: You should've commented before the deletion . . . Now there is no way unless you undelete the post, comment, then delete it again. Even after that, if they didn't have 10k or weren't a dev and couldn't read it, they wouldn't have been to see it when you delete it. Oded sees everything though. o.o

Comment: If it was a bug report, and it turned out what you reported isn't a bug, then the reason you deleted the report is already clear.

Comment: That its not a bug, and that its a browser plug in issue might still be useful to others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to add comments to explain why I deleted it?

If you deleted a post, you first have to undelete it before you can comment. So undelete, comment, and delete it again.

> Should you do that?

No. It is totally useless to comment why you delete it. The only user probably going to read that message is you. Other users aren't helped in any way by commenting like that, and certainly not by undeleting it.

Comment: Answers will be viewed by 10k+ users with much higher probability, so I think leaving a comment for them is not a bad idea.

Comment: Why would a 10K user visit random deleted questions? There is a high probability no one will see it ever again @peterh

Comment: @PatrickHoffman Yes, in the case of questions. In the case of answers, yes they will be probably shown many times. The question is about about questions, and not about answers, this is why I wrote a comment and not a new answer.

Comment: Ah. Okay. Clear @peterh